# set custom oninvalid message from locale

Tags: html, setlocale

I would like to set a custom validation message for the oninvalid message in html. I want to set the message from the locale.

I have tried with triple quotes and double on the key and it still doesn't work.
Any help is welcome.
Here is the code:

```
<h1><fmt:message key="prijava"/></h1>
    <form action="LoginServlet" method="POST">
        <table id="loginTable">
            <tr>
                <td><fmt:message key="korisnickoIme"/>:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username" required="required" required="required" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(<fmt:message key='unesiteKorisnickoIme'/>)" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><fmt:message key="lozinka"/>:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password" required="required" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(<fmt:message key='unesiteLozinku'/>)" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><button type="submit"><fmt:message key="prijaviSe"/></button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```